# How do I update ownerid after autoassignment

Tags: apex

Let's say I have a task with a lookup to a Lead.  I run autoassign on the Lead and the Lead gets autoassigned:

```apex
AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Lead' and Active = true limit 1];
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
//Creating the DMLOptions for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox
dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId = AR.id;
Database.update(lUpdlist, dmlOpts);
```

This runs on a future method for ease.  How do I update the task?  The actual autoassign doesn't run until all the Apex is done.

Comment: Why are you using a future method? If you use normal synchronous code, you can see the effects of the assignment immediately in the same transaction. Assignments themselves are not asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, you gave me that code but by then I already used a future because I didnt' know what the scope of your anti-recursion was.  If the answer is to not use a future, but to use your other answer instead, I'm going to try that now.

Comment: It worked!!!  I implemented your prior thing and it just worked